# Core Plot: Random Colors for Scatter Plot(s)

Tags: core-plot

I'm designing a graph that will have multiple scatter plots on it.  The number of scatter plots changes for each set for data.  I am trying to distinguish the scatter plots by color, however I am running into some trouble.

Currently, I have a for loop that creates a scatter plot for each object in an array.  Inside the for loop, I set a color based off a random number:

lineStyle.lineColor =  [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:((arc4random()%255)/255.0) green:((arc4random()%255)/255.0) blue:((arc4random()%255)/255.0) alpha:1.0];

This works sometimes, however the color sometimes might be too hard to distinguish from other colors, or might be totally white.  Is there a better way to generate random colors (maybe something similar to the way the pie charts generate their colors)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is really anything core-plot specific in this questions, it's really a just a matter of programmatically generating color schemes.

As an idea for how to do that better than just pure random numbers, heres some almost psuedo code for how i would do it:

```
float red = 0;
float blue = 0;
float green = 0;
while(need more colors){
    float colorToInc = (arc4Random()%100)/100;
    float incValue = (arc4Random()%100)/500;//value between 0 and .2
    if(colorToInc < .3){
        red += incValue;
        if(red > 1)
            red -= 1;
    }else if(colorToInc < .7){
        green += incValue;
        if(green > 1)
            green -= 1;
    }else{
        blue += incValue;
        if(blue > 1)
            blue -= 1;
    }
    newcolor = [color with red:red blue:blue green:green];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
red = (arc4random()%100)/100.0;
green = (arc4random()%100)/100.0;
blue = (arc4random()%100)/100.0;
[UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1];
```